# Django email validator language

Tags: python, django, translation, email-validation

I'm developing a Django website in Spanish and using the email field. If the string typed in the form is not an email, it show a built-in error message in English. How can I change it to Spanish?

In my settings.py I have set the language to spanish:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

I also tried adding the following code to views.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

activate('es')
```

Comment: In settings.py, do you have `USE_I18N = True` and do you have "django.core.context_processors.i18n" in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list?

Comment: Also, are you sure `es` is the right language code?  I would have expected something like `es-ES` or `es-MX`.

Comment: Does the Spanish built-in error messages work in other field types, or do you only get English errors?

Comment: @JohnGordon according to wikipedia "es" is correct:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: @JohnGordon I had 'USE_I18N = True' but didn't have the i18n processor. I just tried and still, same error in English.

Comment: @Vingtoft I have the admin panel in Spanish but all error messages are in English.

Comment: Please post your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. Can be found in your settings

Comment: @Vingtoft here they are:
`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error I was seeing had nothing to do with Django, but it's the email validator from the browser, which is displayed in the browser's language as explained by @Yann-Dinendal at [How to change html5 pattern error messages for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630849/how-to-change-html5-pattern-error-messages-for-email)